# Need advice for what to do with this gap in mounting block

Tags: mounting, siding, spigot

This summer, I noticed that there were a lot of wasp near the mounting block and spigot coming out of the siding of my home, which suggested to me that there was probably a wasp nest behind there. Now that it's the end of October in Minnesota, and the wasps have probably died from the cold, when I went to look at what was going on, I noticed that there's this gap between the mounting block and the spigot itself.

[image]
My question is the following:

Since I've read that wasps will die from the freeze in winter, should I just use some caulk to seal the gap and call it a day, or should I really be trying to remove and replace the mounting block and getting rid of the wasp nest in the process? If the latter, I'd really appreciate some feedback on some things to watch out for when replacing the mounting block too.

Comment: That's not a mounting block; they sided over siding? That's a *I need to get around this thing* box. Spray it just because screw them, then caulk it. And put a bead on the bottom gap while you're at it and up the sides a little. An actual mounting block would mean you'd have to pull the spigot and put it through the hole you make in the block. And then it'd be wiggly, so no.... Caulk.

Comment: I took apart a spot hiding an old wasp nest in January of February once. There was a single wasp in there. I just looked it up: Mated females hibernate and seed the next year's hive.

Comment: @popham so the queen was nesting within your siding? It sounds like I will need to probably take it apart somehow after all...